# Finding rows matching positive and negative

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 rows but I need to identify just the rows that offset, meaning the positive amount matches the negative amount, for the same vendor + invoice + check number combination.

```
Vendor_Code  Invoice_Number  Check_Number  Payment_Amount  Subcontract_Job
-----------  --------------  ------------  --------------  ---------------
DEVONEL      6462            35272             8257.50     BUP008
DEVONEL      6462            35272            -8257.50     BUP008
DEVONEL      6462            35665             8257.50     BUP008
```

Only the first two rows should be returned, since the third row doesn't have a matching negative offset.

Comment: How do you define "first 2"?

Comment: So what is the exact criteria for *duplicate*?

Comment: top two with check # 35272

Comment: But how do you know you want check # 35272 and not #35665? Because the number is lower? Or because there exists both a + and - payment amount? Or something else?

Comment: because there exists both a + and - payment amount. they were added by mistake and I need to be able to find them and supress them in a report im doing.

Comment: user2022883 - What keeps your rows in this particular order?

Comment: Just how I sorted them to pull example. What I'm looking for is where check# = Check# and amount = -amount

Comment: So, do you actually want simply to *identify* such rows or to find and *suppress* them?

Comment: right now I just need to identify them. but everything I have tryed has pull in records that it should not. They all are pulling in all matching check #s not just the ones with +,- matching values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT x1.<cols>, x2.<cols> 
FROM dbo.YourTable AS x1
INNER JOIN dbo.YourTable AS x2
  ON x1.Vendor_Code    = x2.Vendor_Code
 AND x1.Invoice_Number = x2.Invoice_Number
 AND x1.Check_Number   = x2.Check_Number
 AND x1.Payment_Amount = -x2.Payment_Amount;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me immensely!  How do you recommend best indexing for this query?

Answer (score 0):

If the amounts are the same (there isn't a rounding difference or some kind of "it is close to" type issue with the amounts - if so think of rounding the amount field or adding/subtracting the margin from it.) then you could do a set based comparison like:

```
Select VendorCode, InvoiceNumber, CheckNumber, Amount from dbo.tablename
intersect
Select VendorCode, InvoiceNumber, CheckNumber, Amount from dbo.tablename
```

And it would give you the list of matching payments. If you just want to find non-matching records you could use Except instead of intersect. (Like if you did the above and passed it into an update incase you had a flag field to mark non-balanced payments in an invoicing system.)

I would use the above in a CTE and then feed that into an update.